# conversion from Tcl to Itcl

Tags: tcl, itcl

i am very new to ITCL can some one help me how to convert following code from Tcl to itcl

```
catch { namespace delete ::HVToolSet }
namespace eval ::HVToolSet { } {
}
proc ::HVToolSet::Main {} {
    if {[winfo exists .main]} {
        destroy .main
    }
    set ::HVToolSet::base [toplevel .main]  
    variable tab_frame
    set x 200
    set y 200
    wm geometry $::HVToolSet::base ${x}x${y}+100+0  
    wm title $::HVToolSet::base "Chevron's Build Effective Stress Results Tool" 
    wm focusmodel $::HVToolSet::base passive    
    set creatFrame [frame .main.mnFrame]
    pack $creatFrame -side top -anchor nw -expand 1 -fill both -padx 7 -pady 7

    button $creatFrame.okbutton -text "OK" -command ::HVToolSet::okcall
    pack $creatFrame.okbutton -side top 
}

proc ::HVToolSet::okcall {} {
    ::HVToolSet::checkRun "right"
}

proc ::HVToolSet::checkRun {val} {
    set abc 10
    ::newspace::exec $abc  # another name space method calling
}

::HVToolSet::Main
```

Comment: I always thought that [incr Tcl] is an extension for Tcl. I suggest adding a `package require Itcl` at the beginning.

Comment: What about the procedures and how we have to represent the procedure calling if the that procedure is from some other namespace?

Answer (score 1):

First off, the mapping is not exact. You're moving from a system without classes to one with, and that's a fundamental and subtle difference.

However, crudely, a procedure becomes a method and a namespace becomes a class. That's at least a first approximation for what to do:

```
package require Itcl

itcl::class HVToolSet {
    # Shared over all instances (and unused otherwise?!)
    common variable tab_frame ""
    # Specific to each instance of this class
    private variable base ""

    # 'Main' seemed to be a constructor of some sort
    constructor {{win .main}} {
        if {[winfo exists $win]} {
            destroy $win
        }
        set base [toplevel $win]  
        set x 200
        set y 200
        wm geometry $base ${x}x${y}+100+0  
        wm title $base "Chevron's Build Effective Stress Results Tool" 
        wm focusmodel $base passive    
        set creatFrame [frame $base.mnFrame]
        pack $creatFrame -side top -anchor nw -expand 1 -fill both -padx 7 -pady 7

        button $creatFrame.okbutton -text "OK" -command [itcl::code okcall]
        pack $creatFrame.okbutton -side top 
    }

    # Obvious destructor...
    destructor {
        destroy $base
    }

    # Callback, best done as private method
    private method okcall {} {
        $this checkRun "right"
    }

    # Public method...
    method checkRun {val} {
        set abc 10
        ::newspace::exec $abc  ; # another name space method calling
    }
}

# Make an instance of the class that operates with the window .main
HVToolSet myInstance .main
```

Working out what needs to be a constructor, what a private method and what a public method can take a bit of thought. Generally, constructors make and initialize things, private methods only make sense within the class (e.g., to handle callbacks or refactor out complex stuff) and public methods may mean something when called externally.